# Why does a tk interface run with no root.mainloop() in IDLE but not PyCharm

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

Why does this code

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()
```

Run successfully in IDLE but **not** in PyCharm,

However this code

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

Run successfully in **both** IDLE and PyCharm

Comment: IDLE mean waiting, APP has an mainloop. Differences of `exec` and `run`, run required a procces holder.

Comment: I think it is because IDLE is based on `tkinter`; that new root may be hogging the idle mainloop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idle is `based` on `tkinter`; this new `root` is hogging the existing `idle` `mainloop`

If you try this in pycharm, two windows will pop:

```
import tkinter as tk


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root2 = tk.Tk()
    root.mainloop()
```